# iOS 8 simulators not visible in XCode 7 beta

Tags: ios8, xcode7

I'm using the **XCode 7 beta** that Apple released during **WWDC2015,** and it looks like iOS8 simulators are not there in it.
I tried downloading them using the `Xcode > Preferences > Downloads > Components,` but it doesn't list the simulators.

I have **Xcode 6.3.2** also on the mac, and iOS8 simulators are visible there.
Any ideas how to make it appear in Xcode 7?

-Tejas

Comment: Both simulators don't seem to be happy running side by side. Both versions of Xcode try to take over the other simulator and then complain that it doesn't support the required version of iOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/WWDC_2015/Xcode_7_beta/Xcode_7_beta_Release_Notes.pdf) of Xcode 7 beta 1 state:

> **Simulator**
>
> • Xcode 7.0 beta does not support iOS 8.4 and earlier simulator runtimes. (20699475)

Answer (score 1):

First, find the target file:

```
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib
```

You need make backup liblaunch_sim.dylib (Just in case). 
Second, copied to destination (**Remember to backup**)

```
/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib
```

And If need it to:
iOS 8.1.simruntime
iOS 8.2.simruntime
iOS 8.3.simruntime
All done.

Hope it helps.