# Simulator not present in XCode 7

Tags: xcode7, ios9

EDIT: I tried this also with XCode 7 beta 2 and I get the same. There are no simulators.

---

I am using XCode 7 beta 1 and I cannot find any iPhone simulator.

None seem to available for download either.

[image]

This is not meant to be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800876/ios-8-simulators-not-visible-in-xcode-7-beta).

Comment: My components box is empty too, however I have the iOS 9.0 simulators installed and available in the devices window (⇧⌘2). Current beta has a known issue to support only iOS9.0 simulators.

Comment: In mine they are not and it won't all me to install them.. annoying

Comment: What if you hit the '+' button in the devices window?

Comment: Doesn't add them.. the rainbow wheel keeps spinning and then at some points stops..

Comment: Not an answer, but did you give beta 2 a shot?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with Xcode 7 beta 2 and found 3 simulators under preferences -> Downloads. 
It compiles and run the iPhone 6 simulator fine. Right now, I'm testing basic functionality but all seems to be working fine.(except playground files)

Hope you were able to try Xcode 7 beta 2.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I do see only iOS 8 simulators

Comment: I believe the only simulators available up to date are: iOS8.3, 8.2, and 8.1. Don't forget to check & install more often to pull Docs and Component updates.

Answer (score 1):

The Xcode 7 beta 3 fixes the simulator problem. It now supports legacy simulators to download. You should be able to download the older simulators except the latest iOS8.x beta.

Link for release notes.

https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7_beta_3/Xcode_7_beta_3_Release_Notes.pdf

Comment: You would need to download the simulator from preferences. I meant it supports the download of legacy simulators. It wasn't supported earlier